# How can I set up the SQL Server permissions to make SSRS utilize a stored procedure rather than an embedded query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I'm trying to set up a SSRS report using a query inside a stored procedure.  I previously had the query embedded in the report, but I wanted to use a stored procedure instead for various reasons.

All of the SSRS reports are run from a SQL Server user named `reporting`.

My stored procedure name is `proc`, and the schema name is `reports`.  For the  user called `reporting`, and granted that user permission to `select` and `execute`. (I think.  See [image: screen shot].)

I can run the stored procedure when I use my full rights account (to confirm that it actually works), and the report works inside the Visual Studio 2012.

When I upload the report onto the reporting server, then attempt to access it through the web browser, I get the following error message:

> The report server cannot process the report. The data source
>   connection information has been deleted.
>   (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can make the report appear as intended?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uploaded the report it lost the rights you have on the proc. You have to enter a user in the Report's Data Source that has execute permission on the stored procedure (it could be you or anyone else as long as you know the password and it has the required rights).

Comment: It worked.  Thanks.  I forgot to mention that I had set up a shared data source to hold the connection string information (within SSRS), and I had to reset it after uploading the SSRS file.  I should have known, since I do that with every report, I just got confused because I was trying so many new things this time.  Thanks.