# SSRS Report in Visual Studio 2019 can query the stored procedure, but can't find it in preview or by running it

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I've got this stored procedure in my database. In the Report Data window I've got my data source pointing to that database. When making a new DataSet it can see the stored procedure, and get all the column headers from it. If I right click on the Dataset and inspect the query I can run the query in that window and it gets me back the proper data that I expect to see in the report.
But when I click the "preview" tab, or when I actually run the report, I get an error back saying that the stored procedure doesn't exist.
I don't know what could be causing this other than perhaps an environment variable that is pointing to a different database than everything else I can find. Does anyone know what might be going on here, or where else I might need to change the database target, so it can find this stored procedure?

I built the report just fine, when I preview it or deploy/run it I expected the data to appear and instead it says that the stored procedure doesn't exist, even though it can find it everywhere else, and can even see the data that's supposed to be in the report when I execute the query in the VS query builder.

Comment: Have you checked the database context and the schema.

Comment: Possibly permissions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357887/how-can-i-set-up-the-sql-server-permissions-to-make-ssrs-utilize-a-stored-proced